# Using hardlinks over network drives

Tags: networking, share, hardlink

I know that you can fsutil hardlink on local drives, however I'd like to be able to hardlink on a network drive over to a different network drive. Is this possible?

I presume not as the two drives are held on seperate machines to each other, and if you could hardlink across networks then you could (I presume) do some wierd stuff to other people's computers. However I wanted to double check my reasoning is right on this, and that there is not a way to do this.

Thanks,
Psy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hardlink over a Network would not really work, it doesn't even work across Filesystems really because if you look at the implementation it is afaik just an inode pointing at the same location as the original inode. 
You might want to look into DRBD or maybe lsyncd so to get the same files in sync across a network.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I ran
 `info ln`

I found this

> On all existing implementations, you cannot make a hard link to a
>   directory, and hard links cannot cross file system boundaries.  (These
>   restrictions are not mandated by POSIX, however.)

Answer (score 0):

Hard links cannot span across multiple file systems. Soft links on the other hand can.